# Any way to face consequence of all good and bad deeds in one life?

Tags: philosophy, karma, moksha, sin

I have committed many paap/sins (broke promise, insult and abuse, dishonesty) and good deeds like helping people, charity.

But good and bad deeds make one to continue material existence.

***What I want to know is there any way to face consequence of all deeds in this life and all previous one? Like I want  to face consequence of karma account(both good/bad)of all lives before dying in this life***

Is there any mantra to request God to give me result of all good and bad acts before dying (vedic mantras expected)

Or any yogic method to face consequence of all sins and deeds before end of this life

Comment: normally, all punya and paap are distributed in a 7-janma rolling window. the biggest virtues and the worst sins committed today will bear fruit within today + 7 janmas. the intensity of pleasure and pain will match that of the virtue/sin you did. with mercy of higher beings like rishis/devatas, they can concentrate these into a shorter time frame. e.g. everyone thinks vishvamitra tortured harischandra to test his truth. but hidden blessing was to remove most of his karma within one life (as you say).

Comment: Now comes the most secret answer to this question - With mercy of highest being (vishnu), if you surrender (sharanagati) - then all your virtues/sins will be over in this ife itself and you attain mukti. I say 'secret' because it is open secret - meaning even if people hear it, they won't understand it, and even if they understand it, they won't do it.

Comment: @mar is there any other method to leave all good and bood karma than to surrender to parambraham??

Comment: no. every action has a reaction. you cannot escape the reaction once you commit the action.

Comment: Any way to get reaction very very quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the context of tantra and Yoga, there are various techniques to get complete enlightenment and get liberated in a single lifetime. Past life impressions or karma are often stored in the astral body (shukshma sharira) that can be burnt in a single lifetime to get enlightenment and quick liberation.

### Raja Yoga

The goal of *Raja Yoga* is *Kaivalya Samadhi*. Here the goal of the yogi is to silence and still the mind from the present as well as previous life accumulation of life impressions of *Pain and Pleasure*. Once *Kaivalya Samadhi* is mastered, all the past life impressions are destroyed and soul gets liberated already while living (Jivanmukta).

> 33. **The resolution in the inverse order of the qualities, perfect of any motive of action for the Purusa, is Kaivalya, or it is the
>     establishment of the power of knowledge in its own nature.**
>
> ~ Yoga Sutras of Patanjali, IV.
>
> Nature’s task is done, this unselfish
> task which our sweet nurse Nature had imposed upon herself. As it
> were, she gently took the self-forgetting soul by the hand, and showed
> him all the experiences in the universe, all manifestations, bringing
> him higher and higher through various bodies, till his glory came
> back, and he remembered his own nature. Then the kind mother went back
> the way she came, for others who have also lost their way in the
> trackless desert of life. And thus she is working, without beginning
> and without end. And thus through pleasure and pain, through good and
> evil, the infinite river of souls is flowing into the ocean of
> perfection, of self-realisation.
>
> Glory unto those who have realised their own nature. May their
> blessings be on us all!

*Commentary by Swami Vivekananda*. Raja Yoga.

> Those who feel ardently for Self-realisation, who have burning
> Vairagya, attain at once to the state of Asamprajnata Samadhi. Burning
> Vairagya and intense Sadhana are needed. Then the fruit is near at
> hand. According to the degree of Vairagya and degree of Sadhana, there
> are nine stages or steps wherein Yogis halt. The fruit of Samprajnata
> Samadhi is Asamprajnata Samadhi, and the fruit of Asamprajnata Samadhi
> is Kaivalya or absolute independence **[*]**.

**Absolute Independence here refers to Liberation*

Swami Sivananda. [*Samadhi*](https://www.sivanandaonline.org/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=924&format=html#:%7E:text=Those%20who%20feel,or%20absolute%20independence.). Date Accessed: 19-01-24

### Tantras

In the context of tantra, there is a wide library of methods to achieve the goal of Raja Yoga very quickly. The principal ones include *Kundalini Yoga*, where the goal is to artificially clean the passages of nadis (through prana), balance chakras, and then arouse the Kundalini to move upward and unite with Sahasrara chakra. Again, there are hundreds of sub-methods to achieve this - Hatha Yoga, Kriya Yoga (of Mahavatar Baba Ji's), Mantra Yoga, Shaktipath initiation, Shava Sadhana, etc.

1. **Hatha Yoga**

> राज-योग-पदं छापि लभते नात्र संशयः | कुम्भकात्कुण्डली-बोधः
> कुण्डली-बोधतो भवेत | अनर्गला सुष्हुम्णा छ हठ-सिद्धिश्छ जायते || ७५ ||
>
> rāja-yogha-padaṃ chāpi labhate nātra saṃśayaḥ |
> kumbhakātkuṇḍalī-bodhaḥ kuṇḍalī-bodhato bhavet | anarghalā suṣumṇā cha
> haṭha-siddhiścha jāyate || 75 ||
>
> He obtains the position of Rāja Yoga undoubtedly. Kuṇḍalinī
>
> awakens by Kumbhaka, and by its awakening, Suṣumnā becomes free from
> impurities.

*Hatha Yoga Pradipika*. [Chapter 2.75](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/hatha-yoga-pradipika-english/d/doc7975.html#:%7E:text=%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C%2D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%97%2D%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BF%20%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0,free%20from%20impurities.). Date Accessed: 19-01-24

2. **Kriya Yoga**

> Kriya Yoga speeds up our spiritual growth in several ways. One of them
> is the rapid burning up of past bad karma. According to our Kriya
> Gurus, kriya helps to increase the current of energy in the astral
> spine. This strong current carries along with it the vrittis of past
> karma — much like a river in flood will sweep away all the stagnant
> eddies and whirlpools, and carry all the old debris to the ocean.

Ananda.[*Kriya Yoga burns up Karma*](https://www.ananda.org/ask/kriya-yoga-burns-up-karma/#:%7E:text=Kriya%20Yoga%20speeds,to%20the%20ocean.). Date Accessed: 19-01-24

3. **Shaktipath Initiation**

In higher tantras, especially traditions of Nathas and Kashmiri Shivaism, there is a way in which a Siddha guru is supposed to impart Kundalini Awakening to the disciple via touching chakras in the body. This leads to **temporary** awakening of Kundalini in disciple and burning of Karma and it returns back to normal. Depending upon the capacity of the disciple, different intensities of initiation is given to them.

> Shaktipata (Sanskrit: शक्तिपात, romanized: śaktipāta)[1] or Shaktipat
> refers in Hinduism to the transmission (or conferring) of spiritual
> energy upon one person by another or directly from the deity.
> Shaktipata can be transmitted with a sacred word or mantra, or by a
> look, thought or touch – the last usually to the ajna chakra or agya
> chakra or third eye of the recipient.
>
> Shaktipata is considered an act of grace (Anugraha) on the part of the
> guru or the divine. It cannot be imposed by force, nor can a receiver
> make it happen.[2] The very consciousness of the god or guru is held
> to enter into the Self of the disciple, constituting an initiation
> into the school or the spiritual family (kula) of the guru.[3] It is
> held that shaktipata can be transmitted in person or at a distance,
> through an object such as a flower or fruit.[4]

Wikipedia.[*Shaktipath*]([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktipata#:~:text=Shaktipata%20(Sanskrit,fruit.%5B4%5D)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktipata#:%7E:text=Shaktipata%20(Sanskrit,fruit.%5B4%5D)). Date Accessed: 19-01-24

While it is possible that a guru can awaken the kundalini of a disciple from a very large distance (even almost from a distance of a different part of the world), the intensity of the feeling is very high, hence a guru nearby physically available is highly recommended in case of emergency.

> The purpose to do shava sadhana varies from person to person. An aim
> of shava sadhana is to **unite the Kundalini with Param Shiva**.[3] From a
> yogic or Tantric point of view, it signifies detachment from the
> physical world, and uniting with the Absolute, identified with the
> male god Shiva, the Divine Mother Shakti or the abstract Brahman. The
> detachment leads to freedom from Samsara (the cycle of birth, death
> and reincarnation) and the adept goes beyond the orthodox concepts of
> purity and impurity; auspiciousness and inauspiciousness.

Wikipedia.[*Shava Sadhana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shava_sadhana). Date Accessed: 19-01-24

Shava Sadhana is a left-handed tantric practice where a corpse from a cremation ground is awakened temporarily to invoke deities, demons while raising kundalini. It is a highly tamsic practice and should not be performed.

Although there are hundreds of ways to do the same, here are some brief different approaches to the goal of Raja Yoga - *Kaivalya Samadhi*.

---

### Dangers of Kundalini Awakening

> The opening of the chakras has been the subject of a tremendous amount
> of focus in the yoga literature, with emphasis on the awakening of the
> kundalini energy at the base of the spine, and the rising up of this
> energy through each of the chakras up to the crown of the head. The
> dangers associated with this process have also been described, as a
> **sudden opening of one of the lower chakras can lead to serious
> psychological and physical imbalances and dangers, particularly if
> there is not a trusted and experienced guide to help one manage the
> experience.**

Sri Aurobindo. [*Kundalini*](https://sriaurobindostudies.wordpress.com/tag/kundalini/#:%7E:text=The%20opening%20of,manage%20the%20experience.). Date Accessed: 19-01-24

> In contrast to this, Sri Aurobindo (a yogi and philosopher from India)
> believed that kundalini in itself would not induce psychosis in a
> previously healthy individual, but that a constitutionally weak
> nervous system, already predisposed to emotional problems, might
> decompensate under the stress of kundalini awakening (especially if
> proper precautions are not observed) [6]. **Similarly, a study reported
> two cases who had been diagnosed as schizophrenia patients but had
> actually been going through a spiritual crisis** (a form of identity
> crisis where an individual experiences drastic changes to their
> meaning system (i.e., their unique purposes, goals, values, attitude
> and beliefs, identity, and focus) typically because of a spontaneous
> spiritual experience.) [7,8].

Hari hara Suchandra, et al., “*Kundalini-like experience as psychopathology: A case series and brief review*”, Complementary Therapies in Clinical Practice, Volume 42, 2021, 101285, ISSN 1744-3881.

> **She ascribed the vibration to some eternal force and considered
> herself to be its passive recipient. She also felt that people around
> her are talking about her, though others repeatedly refuted that, and
> was hearing clear voices, in an awake state, telling her to follow
> orders in her day-to-day activities. Her sleep pattern was disturbed;
> she would frequently get up at night and would often be found doing
> pranayama and meditation.**
>
> **Over a month, she also expressed to have experienced eternal
> enlightenment and would feel that all materialistic things, including
> a person’s basic needs of hunger and thirst, are immaterial to them.
> Initially, her family members also believed these experiences to be an
> outcome of her yoga practices but were later concerned with a gradual
> change in her previous self and social and biological function. This
> change in the patient was not seen as deviance but as an impact of
> yoga practice until she stopped eating, speaking, and interacting with
> others and was found frozen in sustained postures, requiring medical
> attention.**

Sharma M, Dhankar M, Kumar D. *Awakening of Kundalini Chakras Presenting as Psychosis-A Case Report*. Indian J Psychol Med. 2022 Sep;44(5):526-528. doi: 10.1177/02537176221082936. Epub 2022 May 3. PMID: 36157024; PMCID: PMC9460011.

---

In summary, there are clear indications of - schizophrenia, psychosis, and other mental disorders at very advanced stages and levels that almost become untreatable for a lot of people throughout their lives. The sort of disability is via improper kundalini awakening or using violent and unstable methods often leads to problems that aren't even properly understood by medical sciences.

Yes, there are methods to burn past life impressions, but could be harmful and very dangerous if done very quickly and wrong without the aid of a guru. It is always recommended to have slower and more stable progress toward these.

Comment: can you tell me any of scripture which describes kriya yog, not by people (gurus in kaliyug) but in any of sastras?

Comment: @Hope Kriya Yog and the Majority of Tantras are not written in scriptures. 99% of all advanced practices are never written. The *Kriya Yog*, I'm talking about here is Mahavatar Baba Ji's which he himself transmitted to Yogananda and the guru of Sri M. You may read *Autobiography of an Yogi* to know more about it.

Comment: Please note, the gurus of Adi Shankra, Patanajali, Adi Nath (Hatha Yoga), are all claimed to be Mahavatar Baba Ji's. So, half of all techniques I've mentioned have came under the guidance of Adi Nath, Mahavatar Baba Ji only (these are the claims, pl refer Sri M to know more about the claims).

Comment: Do any upnishad Or yog darshan have kriya yog Or  kundalini, so that I can know in detail? Also , I believe in sources from scripture than autobiographies

Comment: @Hope You need to first carefully understand Kundalini Awakening happens immediately after enlightenment (jivanmukta) and past live impressions have finished. This can happen via - jnana, karma or bhakti yog too. In Raja Yoga, it too happens after Kaivalya Samadhi. So yes, there are numerous Upanishads that discuss Kundalini Awakening and Yoga Upanishads that talk about Kundalini Yoga (*Yoga Kundalini Upanishad*). But a word of **warning**, the Yoga Upanishad techniques are **very dangerous** if performed without supervision.

Comment: @Hope I hope you won't fall into the trap of quick and easy fix methods. These are not suitable for everyone, especially those who have a lot of karma left. I've seen people getting suicidal because once there is an error, there isn't a fix to it, unfortunately. This was my warning. If you really wish to approach it, go via Raja Yoga route of Kaivalya Samadhi.

Answer (score 0):

> Vyāsa said — O King! Hear, then the causes that are certainly very wonderful. The seers say that Karma is of three kinds — Sañchita (accumulated), Vartamāna (present) and Prārabdha (commenced). Each of these is again subdivided into three, Sāttvik, Rājasik, and Tāmasik. The accumulated effects of Karmas done in many past lives is called Sañchita, O King! The effects of this Sānchita Karma, be it auspicious or inauspicious, be it for a long or for a short time, must have to be enjoyed by the beings whether they be good or bad. **This Sañchita Karma done by the embodied beings in several previous births, can never be totally exhausted even in hundred Koti Kalpas without their being enjoyed...** *- Srimad Devi Bhagavatam 6.10.6-29*

As you see, you cannot exhaust the effects of your Karmas in even innumerable lifetimes spanning Koti Kalpas, let alone a single lifetime!

Reference -

- [Srimad Devi Bhagavat Puran translated by Swami Vijnanananda](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/srimad-devi-bhagavatam.html)

Comment: I know what you are saying but I am asking a way out, you are just describing my question with reference

Comment: @Hope There is no way out, that's what I said!

Comment: Then why yogis are given moksha. Do they face reaction of every karma in one life

Comment: @Hope When one attains moksha, then this leftover karma gets burned.

Comment: Means if I do karmyog Or gyan yog whole life all sins effect will be cancelled,but if a rapist , adulterer ,murderer or alcoholist do this will he also be freed? (This is what I am doubtful)

Comment: @Hope Every sinner has a future and every saint has a past!